# numpy arrays slicing using reshape

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-slicing

I was learning how to reshape an array. I found several tutorials on the topic. I have confusion after reading all those stuff.

Suppose I declared an array using numpy

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
```

I reshaped it

```
newarr = arr.reshape(4, 3)
```

The resultant array `newarr` which has 4 rows and 3 columns

I found another command for reshaping

```
arr.reshape(data.shape[d1],d2)
```

Here data is the array name d1 = dimension1 and d2= dimension2.

As per my knowledge, shape[0] returns numbers of rows of a 2-d array, shape[1] returns numbers of columns
of a 2d array

if I write down

```
newarr = arr.reshape(arr.shape[4],3)
```

I got an error `tuple index out of range`. Doesn't the previous command mean that create a 2d array with 4 rows and 3 columns?

I also tried the same command for

```
 newarr = arr.reshape(arr.shape[0],1)
```

It works fine with 12 rows and one column, So does this mean shape[0] returns numbers of columns?

I read various tutorials on slicing an array but this is not clear to me.

What happen with newarr = arr.reshape(arr.shape[4],3) command?

Comment: Look at `arr.shape`.  That's just a `tuple`.  `arr.shape[i]` selects the ith element of that tuple, or an error if `i` is too big. Get that right before trying to pass the value to reshape.  `reshape` is a method that accepts numbers.

Answer (score 0):

arr is unidimensional, then only arr.shape[0] is defined

Try printing arr.shape

Answer (score 0):

> I found another command for reshaping
>
> `arr.reshape(data.shape[d1],d2)`

This is not correct, not in the general case anyway. This command makes the first dimension of `newarr` match the d1´th dimension of the array `data`.

You should stick to

```
newarr = arr.reshape(d1, d2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])` is an 1D array, there arent any rows/columns. Its just array of elements with indexing. Your `arr.shape` has only one dimension with 12 values `(12,)`. so, when you call `arr.shape[0]` it returns number of elements in the dimension and it is 12.

So, finally you are asking an `arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])`to reshape to `newarr = arr.reshape(arr.shape[4],3)` where `arr.shape[4]` is out of bound.